Are threats of job loss included in the law definition of 'coercion'?
It has come to my attention that teachers in South Africa are now expected to have their fingerprints taken like a bunch of common criminals or they will lose their jobs.
If your prints are then somehow used against you in a court of law, can you make the defence that the fingerprints were taken amongst the threat of job loss or in other words under duress (Or the evidence was coerced) and then have the case thrown out as fruits-of-the-piosonous-tree?
I see a lot of mentions of physical threats when I read about the legal definition of coercion, but I was wondering if threats of unemployment would also count.

In this case, the supposed coercion comes from the government. A state has wide latitude how they implement the balance between personal freedom and law enforcement.

Are they government employees? It's not uncommon for governments to impose extra requirements on their employees. I'll bet all US FBI agents have their fingerprints taken as part of background checks.

IDK does working for a publicly funded school make you a government employee? Not trying to be funny real question.

@NeilMeyer, unless it is a private school that gets vouchers or some other type of subsidy, then yes.  Because why wouldn't they be?

Your opinion of the policy is irrelevant to the question, and is likely only to provoke downvotes and off-topic comments from people who want to argue about it. I'd suggest removing that part of the question.

For what it's worth, every state of the US requires background checks for teachers, generally including fingerprints. https://checkr.com/resources/articles/teacher-background-checks This has been the case for quite some time and I don't think it's particularly controversial here.

Not only teachers and child care, in the US background checks that commonly require fingerprinting include anybody in healthcare (doctors, nurses, dentists, pharmacy techs), lawyers, real estate agents, stockbrokers, jewelers, even owners of bars and restaurants with alcohol licenses, and establishments that sell lottery tickets. Visa applicants and those who seek naturalization are also fingerprinted.

Every single thing a boss tells you to do is under the threat of job loss.  Written reprimands specifically say this:  "failure to...  will result in further disciplinary action up to and including termination."


If your prints are then somehow used against you in a court of law,
can you make the defence that the fingerprints were taken amongst the
threat of job loss or in other words under duress (Or the evidence was
coerced) and then have the case thrown out as
fruits-of-the-poisonous-tree?

No.
South Africa is among the minority of countries that has a U.S. style exclusionary rule in criminal case. Section 35(5) of the South African Constitution excludes evidence that is obtained unconstitutionally and has a "fruits of the poisonous tree doctrine. Specifically, it says:

Evidence obtained in a manner that violates any right in the Bill of
Rights must be excluded if the admission of that evidence would render
the trial unfair or otherwise be detrimental to the administration of
justice.

The "unfair or otherwise detrimental to the administration of justice" clause, however, makes this test somewhat less absolute than its American cousin.

The factors that the courts have most frequently considered include:
• What kind of evidence was obtained?
• What Charter right was infringed?
• Was the Charter violation serious or was it of a merely technical
nature?
• Was it deliberate, wilful or flagrant, or was it inadvertent or
committed in good faith?
• Did it occur in circumstances of urgency or necessity?
• Were there other investigatory techniques available? • Would the
evidence have been obtained in any event?
• Is the offence serious?
• Is the evidence essential to substantiate the charge?
• Are other remedies available?
I do not wish to be seen as approving this as an exhaustive list of
the relevant factors ....

From the Canadian Supreme Court case of R v. Collins, 28(1987) 1 SCR 265, which has been adopted by the South African courts.
In any case, generally speaking, economic coercion, like conditioning keeping a job on compliance, is not unconstitutional, and is intead legally allowed, particularly if it has some legitimate purpose.
Presumably, one of the main reasons that this practice is in place is to do a fingerprint based criminal background check to make sure that the teacher doesn't have a criminal record of child neglect and abuse, or sex offenses, which would otherwise go undiscovered due to the use of an alias. The inclusion of the fingerprints in a database for future use is just incidental to this primary purpose.
Even if it were deemed coercive, which is unlikely, the exclusionary rule has an "inevitable discovery" exception. So, if the police could have legally taken the suspect's fingerprints when he was suspected of a crime, it could use that evidence in court, and evidence obtained from it, even if it was actually obtained in violation of the suspect's constitutional rights.

It is scary to me that treating teachers like criminals is considered legitimate and people wonder why there are 31 thousand vacant teacher positions in South Africa. So we should just consider this as one of the many reasons not to become a teacher.

@NeilMeyer, "treating teachers like criminals" is a very subjective perception.  I have been fingerprinted and photographed for employment and other purposes and never felt as if I was being treated like a criminal.

Taking finger prints from someone isn't really treating them like a criminal. For example, in  Colorado, where I live, every single lawyer and everyone with a driver's license is finger printed. So are members of many other licensed professions. It isn't a big deal and isn't much of a threat to someone who isn't hiding their identity. Fingerprint exams had a false positive error rate of 0.1% and a false negative rate of 7.5%.  https://blogs.ubc.ca/communicatingchem2019w209/2019/03/20/fingerprint/ And, typically, a fingerprint will not be the sole evidence tying a suspect to a crime.
